# Attributes category not changeable in PDP | Spartacus Telco

Tags: spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

We notice that all product variants are returned in the API `"occ/v2/telcospa/products/{{product}}"` through the property called `"variantMatrix"`, when all properties about categories of base product attributes are returned.

But not find any component in Spartacus utilizing this property, for presenting in the PDP, the product details as well as its attributes category (storage size, color, and any others dinamic attributes), selectable through HTML 'select'.

Enabling the user to change attribute options according to their choice in the PDP, and each change corresponds to a product variant and its SKU. Very similar user experience with wireframe extracted from an ongoing project by the Spartacus team as shown below:

[image: wireframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variantMatrix` is used by so called "Multidimensional Product support" (Multi-d Variants) feature of Hybris (B2B extensions). It's not yet implemented in Spartacus due to API missings. However it's developed under `epic/multi-d` branch, you will find the `variantMatrix` usage there:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/commits/epic/multi-d

AFAIK, multi-d variants will become a feature lib, but pls take some time for exploring the project board for details:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/projects/119#card-51242735

And the official roadmap with a mention of Multidimensional product support:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacus-roadmap/

Please note that while Multi-d variants are B2B feature, it should be doable to make use of it for B2C setup after some backend adjustments.